# Are there any simple functions which map $\mathbb Z^n\to \mathbb Z\setminus \{k\}$ for given integer $k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Obviously, a function could be explicitly constructed as the set of all points in $\mathbb Z^n$ and what they are mapped to such that the given integer $k$ is not in the range.  I am hoping to find a function along the lines of a polynomial in no more than $3$ variables.

The motivation for this comes from every scenario where I would want a "one element missing" subset of $\mathbb Z$, for example, $\mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$.  As an extension, consider polynomials which would generate all but a finite set of the integers, for example $\mathbb Z\setminus\{0,-1,10\}$.  Specifying that a given variable is from $\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ is not a problem, but I would like to have an alternate way of guaranteeing such a condition.

The best outcome is that functions $f$ satisfying these conditions are bijections from $\mathbb Z^n$ to the chosen set.

All the polynomials I have thought of so far either include the values that I don't want included, or exclude more values than I want excluded.

Comment: If the domain is $\mathbb{Z}$ then it is of one variable. If it is a polynomial it is monotonic for large values of the variable. Then, since it cannot miss any large value we must have that it is equal to $x+n$ for some $n$. But then it doesn't miss any value. So, it cannot be a polynomial.

Comment: @ABC:  Thank you, I will clarify the question to be $\mathbb Z^n$.